# Unable to create converter for class com.anyarscaner.model.ResponModel

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I created the Retrofit API function, but it's an obstacle like the following. I corrected it yesterday, but after today it returned to the same problem. Here's the Error.

```
Unable to create converter for class com.anyarscaner.model.ResponModel
```

here's my API code

```
ApiConfig.instanceRetrofit.totalPoin(tv_nama.text.toString()).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponModel>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponModel>, response: Response<ResponModel>) {
                val respon = response.body()!!
                s.setString(s.total_poin, respon.total_poin).toString()

                pbPoin.visibility = View.GONE

                if (respon.success == 1) {
                    val getPoin = s.getString(s.total_poin)
                    tv_poin.text = getPoin
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponModel>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Terjadi Kesalahan: "+t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
```

here's my Model Response class

```
class ResponModel {
    var success = 1
    var error = 0
    lateinit var message:String
    lateinit var total_poin: String
}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: what does your http response look like when this error occurs, post the json you're receiving

Comment: Did you use or set any of the Json Converters to your retrofit? By default, Retrofit can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's `ResponseBody` type and it can only accept its `RequestBody` type for `@Body`. If you are not you can use one of the converter [here (In CONVERTERS section)](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) .